# .net version of sqlite not working on visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I have installed .net version of sqlite but i am still getting this error in visual studio 2015.
Project 14 is basically a windows form application.

```
Error   C2039   'SQLite': is not a member of 'System::Data' Project14
```

Comment: To answer your question would need to know which specific SQLite .net package you are using (there are several different ones in existence) and how you installed it and whether you added a reference to it from your project.

Comment: figured out the way. :)

Comment: Would be good to know how you figured it out. I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Right click on external dependencies and add all files in the System.data.sqlite\bin directory. then copy all the dll files from the same directory and paste in in the project directory.